# how can I prevent my widget from running if there is no internet connection?

Tags: android, widget

I am making a weather widget. If I install the widget on the home screen, app configuration starts automatically. I'd like to prevent the configuration from running if there is no wifi or 3g. I used ConnectivityManager in the instance of AppWidgetProvider, but it didn't work. And I used ConnectivityManager in the java class of widget configuration, but it still didn't work with error messages "..stopped unexpectedly." Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Did you add uses-permissions to your manifest file to access the network state? If not you should add them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add network permissions to the Manifest to check network availability. And don't forget about the internet permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Here's a helper class to check network availability:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkUtils
{ 
    public static boolean isOnline(Service service)
    {
        ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) service.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return isOnline(mgr);
    }

    public static boolean isOnline(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return isOnline(mgr);
    }

    private static boolean isOnline(ConnectivityManager mgr)
    {
        NetworkInfo netInfo = mgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```